# Proof of a ring property

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Prove that, for every $a, b$  in $R$, $(-a)b = -(ab) = a(-b)$

Now what I did was:

1) $ab + (-a)b = (a-a)b$ (distributivity) $= 0b$ (additive inverse) $= 0$ (can easily be proved by ring axioms) and similarly, $(-a)b + ab = 0$.

2) $ab + (-ab) = 0 = (-ab) + ab$ (additive inverse of $ab$)

3) $ab + a(-b) = a(b-b) = a0 = 0$ (similar to the first)

And it can be proven that the additive inverse is unique for each element in a ring, therefore $(-a)b = -(ab) = a(-b)$.

Are there any mistakes with this?

Comment: Should it be $-(ab)$ instead of $(-ab)$ in 2)?

Comment: Oh... is this a notation error? I suppose that for every element k with an inverse, k + (-k) = k + (-(k))... but the right hand side seems a bit too much. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah it was a notational note just to distinguish between $(-ab)$ and $-(ab)$; the latter is the additive inverse of $ab$ but the former could be confused for the additive inverse of $a$ times $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good. The proof works. I have no criticisms, but I do have a couple of small, largely stylistic pointers:

- You can use the commutativity of the additive group to show that $(-a)b + ab = 0$ instead of saying "similarly".
- The second line of logic is not really necessary here; you showed in 1) and 3) that $(-a)b$ and $a(-b)$ both satisfy the definition of an additive inverse of $ab$, which means they are equal by the uniqueness of inverses, and we name such an element $-(ab)$.

Comment: Yeah I see exactly what you mean... especially for the second comment, I tend to be too careful because I am not yet proficient in this kind of stuff, which leads me to add non-needed things to my proofs. Thanks!